# Which is best? temporary table or classic materialized?

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Could you tell me one thing,what would be faster ?

1. Delete from work table , insert into work table and then insert transformated data (not much transformations) to target table
2. Insert into temporary table then insert from temporary to target(end) table

If you have some good documentation where I can find answer for such performance questions please share :) Thanks!

Best Regards,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

When the target table is empty, it's the same performance for permanent vs. temporary.

There's only different behaviour when the job fails, the temp table is deleted when the session logs of.